# mysql/php - select dates outside specified two date range

Tags: php, mysql, date

what query should i use to get list of dates outside two given dates(which is coming from saved data in table eg. date1 date2)

for example if table dates is

```
date1    |date2
2016-9-5 |2016-9-10
2016-9-13|2016-9-15
```

the output should be dates outside of date1 to date2 like: 2016-9-4, 2016-9-3...and so on. and 2016-9-11, 2016-9-12... 2016-9-16 and so on

the datatype i use is date

Comment: Where do the outside dates come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the outside dates from table because there are not outside dates in table. But you can write program to get the outside dates.
Call the date1 and date2 from table and

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
Date date = date1;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RESULT && !date.after(date2): i++) {
  date = DateUtils.addDays(date, 1);
  dates.add(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (just an example since you didn't provide a table structure and a desired result):

```
SELECT date FROM table where date<date1 AND date>date2
```

this will select all the rows that are not between date1 and date2

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

this will select all rows that are between date1 and date2.

These statements are valid if `date1<date2`